# Image loader cant load my live image url

Tags: android, lazylist

In my application i need to load the images in list view, when using locale(ip ported url) then no problem all images are loading properly, But when using live url then the images are not loading,

My image loader class:

```
public class ImageLoader {
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.appointeesample;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

        imageViews.put(imageView, url);

        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {

            Log.d("stub", "stub" + stub_id);

            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 81960);
            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(bis, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);

            Log.d("bitmap", "Bit map" + bitmap);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {

            try {

                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
                int scale = 1;

                while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                        && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale *= 2;
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null,
                        o2);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } finally {
                System.gc();
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
```

My Live Image url for Example: `https://goappointed.com/images_upload/3330Torana_Logo.JPG`

I have referred google but no solution is working, Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: are you connected to internet?

Comment: Yes, In manifest given permission for INTERNET also i am checking in real device.

Comment: can you try any other image in HTTP not HTTPS

Comment: ya first i have tried with http, after that only changed to https.

Comment: what do you mean by locale(ip ported url)?

Comment: the url which is pointed local ip (192.168.100.56) something like that,

Comment: can you open the image in browser on your device?

Comment: yes i can open in browser, but its not loading in my application.

Comment: try clearing cache before setting the image

Comment: i will try to clear the cache

Comment: @Bindhu which image loader api are you using?

Comment: @pratik i dint get, image loader api??

Comment: Using which thing are you loading images?

Comment: Things which you have used is Universal Image Loader, I suggest you to use Android Query for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55306/discussion-between-pratik-and-bindhu).

Comment: @pratik This is NOT Universal Image Loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend a different way that works like a charm: Android Query.

You can download that JAR file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list)

```
AQuery androidAQuery = new AQuery(this);
```

As an example:

```
androidAQuery.id(YOUR IMAGEVIEW).image(YOUR IMAGE TO LOAD, true, true, getDeviceWidth(), ANY DEFAULT IMAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW);
```

It's very fast and accurate, and using this you can find many more features like animation when loading, getting a bitmap (if needed), etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great solution and very simple